# Que microframework devo usar?

Tags: php, framework

Atualmente estou estou estudando o **[Fat-Free Framework](http://fatfreeframework.com/)** porem estou me debatendo com muitos problemas algumas funções simplesmente não funcionam como deveriam, e outras se comportam de maneira bem diferente do que é documentada, como ainda estou somente estudando o framework fico com receito de usa-lo em uma aplicação real.

Com isso fico na duvida, como o **F3** está se tornando complicado qual alternativa de framework eu poderia usar ?

Comment: cara, muda a pergunta para algo mais direto: "Que microframework devo usar?" ou algo assim.

Comment: @Daniel Obrigado, fiquei na na duvida de como titular a minha questão.

Comment: Essa é uma pergunta muito particular, tem *N* frameworks disponíveis. Zend e Cake eu acho um elefante branco, Kohana e Laravel nunca usei além do *demo*, mas parece-me que são os que tem a menor curva de aprendizado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Então, só numa busca rapidassa no Google por `php microframework` você já acha de cara as seguintes:

[Lumen, que é baseada no Laravel](https://lumen.laravel.com/)

[Silex, que usa componentes do Symfony](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/)

[Slim](https://www.slimframework.com/)

[Flight](http://flightphp.com/)

Nenhum desses eu usei. Já usei o [FatFree](http://fatfreeframework.com/) que me atendeu, e já usei o [Epiphany](https://github.com/jmathai/epiphany) pra um projeto que estava rodando um servidor capenga `IIS` que rodava uma versão meio antiga do PHP (e nem usei ele todo, só umas poucas coisas).

Na real, microframeworks servem pra você não usar tudo, construir bastante coisa no braço, seja por que você quer aprender ou por que o projeto é muito pequeno e uma framework robusta vai atrapalhar mais do que ajudar. Onde trabalhei, usavam a [Zend](https://framework.zend.com/) e eram bem felizes, mas quando fui tentar aprender fiquei coçando a cabeça e desisti.

Comment: Agora que percebi, em um outro comentário você me indicou o F3, mas em testes das funções ele deu muitos erros, eu estou vendo sobre esse Laravel achei interessante e a documentação enorme. agora me resta saber a diferença entre o Lumen e o Laravel puro.